# Generate a simple HTML table with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I use XSLT to generate an HTML table using info from an XML file. 
I want only 4 TD in every TR.

It works fine on Chrome and Safari. Not in Firefox. I understand that Firefox doesn't support 'disable-output-escaping' so I know that is the problem (it just writes  on the web page) . Is there another way to generate this kind of (simple) table with XSLT on client side?

My code looks like this:

```
<table>
<xsl:for-each select="movies/movie">
   <xsl:if test="(position() = 1) or ((position() mod 4) = 1)">
       <!-- This is a <tr> -->
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;tr&gt;</xsl:text>
   </xsl:if>
   <td>
     <!-- Some stuff goes here. -->
   </td>
   <xsl:if test="((position() mod 4) = 0) or (position() = last())">
       <!-- This is a </tr> -->
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/tr&gt;</xsl:text>
   </xsl:if> 
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of the XML that you're transforming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <table>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="movies/movie[position() mod 4 = 1]"/>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="movie">
    <tr>
      <xsl:for-each select=". | following-sibling::movie[position() &lt; 4]">
        <td>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </td>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input XML:

```
<movies>
  <movie>a</movie>
  <movie>b</movie>
  <movie>c</movie>
  <movie>d</movie>
  <movie>e</movie>
  <movie>f</movie>
  <movie>g</movie>
  <movie>h</movie>
</movies>
```

Output XML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>e</td>
    <td>f</td>
    <td>g</td>
    <td>h</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks! This must be the XSLT way :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this?

```
<table>
<tr><xsl:apply-templates select='movies/movie' /></tr>
</table>
```

And then, in another template

```
<xsl:template match='movie'>
   <td><xsl:value-of select='.' /></td>
</xsl>
```

Remember that you should try and think about XSLT as a template system, more than as a programming language. Using XSLT-specific constructs is usually more straightforward than trying to translate other constructs.